# how do you stop and deallocate a windows azure virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

If I shutdown a virtual machine in azure, it shows it's status as 'stopped'.  But I am still getting billed for cores until I can get the machine into a 'stopped (deallocated)' state.

How do I get the machine to go from 'stopped' to 'stopped (deallocated)' in the management portal?

Answer (score 8):

Found it.  So even though the machine is 'stopped' (which means it isn't running) the shutdown button in the management portal is still enabled.  Clicking 'Shutdown' moves the virtual machine into a 'stopped(deallocated)' status.

So powering down from inside the virtual machine operating system isn't the same thing as an azure 'shutdown'.

Comment: How do you do this from the new portal?  portal.azure.com.  I only see the option in the old portal for classic VMs.

Comment: that is super confusing and I don't understand why after several years it is still like this! I can imagine many customers being charged when they think they should not be. Is there any logic in this, why a stopped machine can be stopped again and is there a reason to have stopped but still allocated VM?

Answer (score 2):

In the new portal, select the "stop" button to get to the [deallocated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhDaV.jpg) state.